# Rspec assigns fails on adding more code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Controller: Test fails if:

```
 def index
    @products = Product.all
    @products.present? ? @no_products_found = "" : @no_products_found = "No Products available."
 end
```

Fail Message: 
            expected: 2
            got: 0

```
   (compared using ==)
```

Rspec:

```
it "assigns products" do
  get :index
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 1")
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 2")
  expect(assigns(:products).size).to eq(2)
end
```

It passes if I change the action to :

```
 def index
    @products = Product.all
 end
```

PS: New to rails. Thanks for your input.

Comment: What is the exact failure message you are getting from RSpec?

Comment: expected: 2 got: 0  (compared using ==)

Comment: Are you cleaning your database? I would have expected the `FactoryGirl` lines before the `get :index` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `FactoryGirl.create` before doing the `get`. Naturally, the records have to exist before the request is made.

```
it "assigns products" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 1")
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 2")
  get :index
  expect(assigns(:products).size).to eq(2)
end
```

Although I would personally make the spec a bit more explicit:

```
it "assigns products" do
  get :index
    products = [
      FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 1"),
      FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 2")
    ]
    expect(assigns(:products)).to eq(products)
  end
end
```

Then there is another problem with your controller action. The ternary conditional operator should be used sparingly and in this case I would strongly advise against using it, because it hinders readability. This line:

```
@products.present? ? @no_products_found = "" : @no_products_found = "No Products available."
```

should be written as

```
@no_products_found = @products.present? ? "" : "No Products available."
```

or even

```
@no_products_found = if @products.present?
                       ""
                     else
                       "No Products available."
                     end
```

again, I would personally prefer not to mess up my controller actions with this kind of simple view logic. Probably it is only used in a single place so my solution would reside entirely in the view layer:

```
<% if @products.present? %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <!-- Render products -->
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No products available.
<% end %>
```

Comment: A slightly off-topic question - If I add the logic in a view then, how would I test if a page displayed  "No products available." or not. I tried should_have_content but that isn't working as expected

Comment: You can do assertions on the rendered body, for example `expect(response.body).to include('No results found')`. You might also want to take a look into feature specs with capybara. These tests spin up a real web browser in the background to simulate user interaction. They are great for end-to-end tests but I like to only weite a few for the core functionality because they tend to get slow.

Comment: True, I just read that it's not common practice to create tests for content view. You can assume that html will display stuff. However if someone must add tests then use helpers to display this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're creating products after making call to index method. Change spec to this:

```
it "assigns products" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 1")
  FactoryGirl.create(:product, name: "product 2")
  # created products above and then make call to index:
  get :index
  expect(assigns(:products).size).to eq(2)
end
```

Comment: Sweet, I just figured that out and was about to post the answer. But, why does it pass in the first case?

Comment: @AdRoiT : I am sorry but I don't see any other case written on your post. Did you miss to write it?

Comment: The same test runs when I define index  def index
    @products = Product.all
 end

Comment: No buddy, that has nothing to do with this, actually, it would have worked second time because the old products(created last time) have had existed in the next call, it won't work if you would have used dbcleaner to clean the db before running specs. :)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks. Appreciate your time.